# Django - How to make the topics, that you create public? Learning Log Project

Tags: html, django, checkbox

## The Problem

I'm trying to make a project, where you can make topics, that can be private or public to unauthenticated users. In every topic, you can then make several entries, applying to that topic. Now I'm trying to make a checkbox in my `new_topic.html`, where if you check it, it evaluates to True, if not, to False. But I'm having trouble with making the checkbox evaluate to True, when I check it. And for some reason, there is two checkbuttons in the page that applies to `new_topic.html`; one with a label, and one with just a box.

## What I've tried

1. I've tried recreating the `db.sqlite3` database. But that didn't work.
2. I've tried using `request.POST.get('public', False)` in my `new_topic()` function, when saving the new_topic variable.¨

## The Code

My `learning_logs/models.py` looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        # Add an ellipsis ONLY if the entry,
        # is more than 50 characters long.
        if self.text > self.text[:50]:
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
        elif self.text <= self.text[:50]:
            return self.text[:50]
```

My `learning_logs\views.py` looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

def index(request):
    """The Home Page for Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def check_topic_owner(request, topic):
    """Checks if the topic requested, is requested by the owner.
       Else return Http404.
    """
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

@login_required
def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

@login_required
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=topic_id)
    # Make sure the Topic belongs to the current user.
    check_topic_owner(request, topic)

    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
            new_topic.owner = request.user
            new_topic.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for the particular topic."""
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=topic_id)
    check_topic_owner(request, topic)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            if new_entry.topic.owner == request.user:
                new_entry.save()
            else:
                return Http404
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',
                                                args=[topic_id]))

    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)

@login_required
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    """Edit an existing entry."""
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic
    check_topic_owner(request, topic)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Initial request; pre-fill form with the current entry.
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',
                                                args=[topic.id]))

    context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)
```

My `learning_logs\forms.py` looks like this:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Topic, Entry

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

My `learning_logs\templates\learning_logs\new_topic.html` looks like this:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block header %}
  <h2>New topic:</h2>
{% endblock header %}

{% block content %}

  <h1>Add a new topic:</h1>
  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}" method='post'
      class="form">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}

    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=True id="public">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="public">
        Make it public?
      </label>
      </input>
    </div>

    {% buttons %}
      <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Topic</button>
    {% endbuttons %}

  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

I just can't seem to fix this error. Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The tag _input_ does not close with `</input>`. It is just `<input ... />`, so you can't put a label tag inside.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Can you give me an example? It would be really helpful.

Comment: @Lauritis L. L. I posted as an answer, I understand that is what you need?

Comment: @guillermochamorro Thanks a lot! I got it. Now there is one checkbox, and if you check it, it evaluates to True! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=True id="public">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="public">
       Make it public?
      </label>
  </input> # <<< this closing tag is wrong
```

correct `input` tag :

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=True id="public" />
```

So you'll have:

```
<label class="form-check-label" for="public">
 Make it public?
</label>
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=True id="public" />
```